# Interfaces & Sub-classes with different types

Tags: vb.net

I have the following situation, that I'm pretty sure can be solved through the use of interfaces, but am not quite experienced enough to implement and keep losing myself.

```
Public Class IPGateway
  Property Hostname As String
  Property Port As Integer
  Public Function Read()
     Return OtherClass.Read(Hostname, Port)
  End Sub
End Class

Public Class SerialGateway
  Property Port As String
  Property Baud As Integer
  Public Sub Read()
    Return YetAnotherClass.Read(Port, Baud)
  End Sub
End Class


Public Sub Main()
  Dim GatewayList as New List(of Gateways?) <- Interface here?
  GatewayList.Add(SerialGateway)
  GatewayList.Add(IPGateway)
  For each gateway in GatewayList
   Console.Write(gateway.Hostname() OR gateway.Baud)
   Console.Write(gateway.Read())
  Next
End Sub
```

I would welcome advice on how to best implement this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 choises, one with Abstract Classes (MustInherit for VB) and one with interfaces. You have to decide which one works best for you!

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("With Abstract Classes")

    Dim GatewayList As New List(Of TheBase)
    GatewayList.Add(New SerialGateway With {.Baud = 5, .Port = "10"})
    GatewayList.Add(New IPGateway With {.Hostname = "Test", .Port = "15"})
    For Each gateway In GatewayList
        Console.WriteLine(gateway.Port)
        If TypeOf gateway Is SerialGateway Then
            Console.WriteLine(DirectCast(gateway, SerialGateway).Baud)
        ElseIf TypeOf gateway Is IPGateway Then
            Console.WriteLine(DirectCast(gateway, IPGateway).Hostname)
        End If

        Console.WriteLine(gateway.Read())
    Next


    Console.WriteLine("With Interface")

    Dim GatewayList2 As New List(Of TestIn)
    GatewayList2.Add(New SerialGateway2 With {.Baud = "5", .Port = "10"})
    GatewayList2.Add(New IPGateway2 With {.Hostname = "Test", .Port = "15"})
    For Each gateway As TestIn In GatewayList2
        Console.WriteLine(gateway.Port)
        Console.WriteLine(gateway.Property2)

        Console.WriteLine(gateway.Read())
    Next

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

End Module

Public Class IPGateway
    Inherits TheBase

    Property Hostname As String

    Public Overrides Function Read() As String
        Return "IPGateway"
    End Function
End Class

Public Class SerialGateway
    Inherits TheBase
    Property Baud As Integer

    Public Overrides Function Read() As String
        Return "SerialGateway"
    End Function
End Class

Public MustInherit Class TheBase
    Public Property Port As String
    Public MustOverride Function Read() As String
End Class

Public Interface TestIn
    Property Port As String
    Property Property2 As String

    Function Read() As String
End Interface

Public Class SerialGateway2
    Implements TestIn

    Public Property Port As String Implements TestIn.Port
    Public Property Baud As String Implements TestIn.Property2

    Public Function Read() As String Implements TestIn.Read
        Return "SerialGateway2"
    End Function
End Class

Public Class IPGateway2
    Implements TestIn

    Public Property Port As String Implements TestIn.Port
    Public Property Hostname As String Implements TestIn.Property2

    Public Function Read() As String Implements TestIn.Read
        Return "IPGateway2"
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you for your guidance, I have elected to use the abstract class approach as it keeps intellisense working and I think it is easier to read/maintain than having properties named Property2, Property3, etc.